# Long response time from server, what to show instead of a loading image?

Tags: web-app, response-time, loading

I have an API of Web Service, which has a long response time in some cases.
What should I show instead of a regular loading image to keep the users feel good (so that users do not get frustrated)?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

The above is a example of what most website did when loading their page.

[image]
There's many approaches to this, but my take is that instead of showing a big loading images, what you can do is to load the wireframe first which should not take long, while loading the content at the background.

With this approach, there's at least 2 advantage over the traditional approach.

1. User can start to familiarize with the layout of the page. More useful if the loading page layout is different from the inital page.
2. User can view the item that got loaded first instead of waiting for all to download finished.

I believe your user will feel better. =) Cheers.

Comment: Very Good approach Man, but can we have any other then the Loading image ?

Comment: You can try to rotate your brand-logo-icon continuously if you have one.

Comment: That really depends on your website. If it's a gaming website such as gamespot.com , you can actually put simple games while loading. Like snake or tetris.

If it's a informative website such as nationalgeographic.com , you can offer some FYI like "Do you know that Ants are capable of carrying objects 50 times their own body weight with their mandibles."

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether the action is blocking or non-blocking, and on the response time expected. Some good resource is the following article: http://www.nngroup.com/articles/response-times-3-important-limits/

Basically if the wait time is below 10 second, a blocking loading dialog is acceptable. 
If the time is above that, or the action is non-blocking then the user should be allowed to run the action in background, and perform other actions while waiting.

One possibility is to show the loading progress bar, with a button saying "run in background", below is an example from Eclipse. 
[image]

Comment: if i dont know how much will be response time then how can i apply the actual Progress bar thing ?

Comment: If you don't know how much time it will take,  you can use an indeterminate progress (ring or bar). Here is an example from Windows UI guidelines :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465469.aspx